# Generating unique vectors using randi

Tags: random, vector, unique, octave

I want to randomly generate 6 vectors using randi, but I want to add specific parameters for what can be generated. First, I don't want any vectors to be duplicates. What can I add to make them unique?

```
n=4;
t1= randi([0,1], 1,4)    
t2= randi([0,1], 1,4)
t3= randi([0,1], 1,4)
t4= randi([0,1], 1,4)
t5= randi([0,1], 1,4)
t6= randi([0,1], 1,4)
```

Comment: First of all, using variable names like `t1` and `t2` is going to make things really tedious. Instead, you can use a cell array, so that you use `t{1}`, `t{2}` and so on. Now you can have a simple loop for your code: `for i=1:6, t{i}=randi(...); end`. Now it's easy to, for each vector you generate, to compare it to all previous vectors. ---- Alternatively, you can use the rows of a matrix as vectors: `t=randi(...,6,4)`, then index `t(1,:)`, `t(2,:)` etc.